# how to delete folder in laravel with prefix

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-filesystem

im using laravel 5.4 and i want to delete folder. how can i delete a folder with a prefix using file facade?

for example it is my folder and code :

```
$folder = public_path().'/images/carimages/something_folder1';


File::deleteDirectory($file);
```

and now i want to do this : delete `*_folder1` (all folders which will ends with `_folder1` word)

------- Soloution :

```
$dir = public_path().'/images/carimages/*_folder1';
$dir = glob($dir);
$dir = implode(" ",$dir);
File::deleteDirectory($dir);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can delete folder by PHP function [rmdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php) for example

```
if (!is_dir('examples')) {
    mkdir('examples');
}

rmdir('examples');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) method

First, get all the directories that you are looking for

```
$files_directory = [];
$file_search_directory = public_path()./images/carimages/';
$file_search_results = exec('find '. $file_search_directory . ' -type d -name "*_folder"', $files_directory);
```

Then you could loop through the files directory and delete them

```
foreach ($files_directory as $file_path) {
    File::deleteDirectory($file_path);
}
```

Comment: i can do it with this : array_map('rmdir', glob('*_folder1'));  . is this good ?

Comment: Well If that works for you, good. There's always more than one way to achieve your goal! and your method seem short and precise! Consider adding that as an answer

Comment: thank you . is there any different between file facade and php rmdir function in performance or security??

Comment: I don't think so there is any difference as you could check the code here https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php#L525 it uses `unlink` and `rmdir` internally

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $files = File::directories(base_path('/images/carimages'));
    foreach($files as $file) {
        if (strpos($file, '_folder1') !== false) {
            File::deleteDirectory($file);
        }
    }
```